# get_absolute_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django

I imagine the solution to this can be found i similar topics, however, it seems a little bit different from problems I have seen.

The `redirect`, in `add_post` view, should send me to the `Post` class, where I have a `get_absolute_url`.

But it happens that I get the following error message: `get_absolute_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I literally copied the coded form the ["Django Projects Cookbook"](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/djenofdjango/en/latest/chapter4.html) in case you wanna check it out and try the code yourself.

Thank you.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render_to_response, get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def add_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect(Post) # redirect to Post class
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html',{ 'form': form })

def view_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect(request.path)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_post.html',{'post': post,'form': form,})
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self): # get_absolute_url 
        return ('blog_post_detail', (), { 'slug' :self.slug, })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `Post` *class*, not its object to redirect. You thus need to use `post` in:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            post = form.save()
            return redirect(post)
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html',{ 'form': form })
```

The [**`@permalink`** decorator was removed in Django-2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1), it is advised to use [**`reverse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) instead:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Furthermore [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) is no longer supported since January 1, 2020; so you might want to update to [django-3.x](/questions/tagged/django-3.x) in a [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) environment.

Comment: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem. But them i get a different error: `quote_from_bytes() expected bytes`

Comment: @Igor: can you please share the *full* traceback? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63043882/edit) the question.

Comment: By changing `Post` to `post` and using `reverse` worked properly. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your syntax to build the `view` is more "suitable" than mine? It shows `local variable 'form' referenced before assignment` when I execute the code. Btw, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

form.save() returns None like some other methods in python, instead I would do this:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def add_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect(post) # Not the model Post, but the object
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html',{ 'form': form })
```

after post.save() which instantiating class, variable(post) transform into object which we can use in redirect() which as default use get_absolute_url() from instantiated objected. So you were almost correct.